# Computing the limit of $ \frac{1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3}{\sqrt{4n^8 +1}} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I had this exercise:

> Compute the limit
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3}{\sqrt{4n^8 +1}} $$

I tried two different approaches and got different answers.

**Approach 1:**

$$\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3}{n^4\sqrt{4 +1/n^8}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1^3}{n^4}+\frac{2^3}{n^4}+\cdots+\frac{n^3}{n^4}}{\sqrt{4 +1/n^8}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1^3}{n^4}+\frac{2^3}{n^4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{4 +1/n^8}}\\
&= \frac{0}{\sqrt{4+0}}\\
&= 0\\
\end{split}$$

**Approach 2:**

We substitute sum of cubes of $n$ natural numbers in the numerator and get

$$\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4n^4\sqrt{4 +1/n^8}}&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4n^4\sqrt{4 +1/n^8}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^4(1+\frac{1}{n})^2}{4n^4\sqrt{4 +1/n^8}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^2}{4\sqrt{4 +1/n^8}}\\ 
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{4\sqrt{4}}\\
&= \frac{1}{8}\\
\end{split}$$

I'm not sure why the two methods are giving me different answers and which one is correct?

Comment: 1/8 is correct ${}{}{}$

Comment: The first method does not work, since you have an infinite number of terms. Think for example about $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1n$$

Comment: You are using limit arithmetic on a sum of $n$ terms, which is problematic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first attempt, $n$ is also present as the number of terms. You cannot use "the limit of the sum is the sum of the limit" in that case. The same way you cannot say
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n=\sum_k0=0.
$$
In this example the sum is $1$ for all $n$, and so the limit is $1$.

Answer (score -1):

One more method is to see the Laurent series of the expression. It is equal to $$\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{4n}+\frac{1}{8n^2}-\frac{1}{64n^8}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^9\right)$$
You can see that it confirms your second approach.